# Ext.Net 2.1 is it possible to create custom user controls?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, ria, ext.net

I've tried to find way how i can create custom user control with ext.net, but unsuccessfull. What i've tried and found:

1) Create .ascx user control - it is impossible to add this control to ext.net parent, only through control loading, but

2) if i load control through UserControlLoader, i have control successfully loaded, but direct events don't works inside loaded control.

3) Extend ext.net controls - with this option there are impossible to use XML markup for control UI.

So, does anybody knows any best practices how i can split my application UI and UI logic into different parts?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the following Ext.NET UserControl related samples can help, see http://examples.ext.net/#/search/usercontrol